# Connection authentication failure JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, derby

When calling this method in the main project class, filling in parameters etc, I receive an error. The field in the table is listed as `ID` and I am receiving user input from the user field comparing it to the `ID` field in the SQL table. If the input from the user matches the `ID` field and `PASSWORD` field from the SQL table, it should send the user to the Main GUI screen. However, this is not the case.

Error:

`run:
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Comparisons between 'INTEGER' and 'CHAR (UCS_BASIC)' are not supported. Types must be comparable. String types must also have matching collation. If collation does not match, a possible solution is to cast operands to force them to the default collation (e.g. SELECT tablename FROM sys.systables WHERE CAST(tablename AS VARCHAR(128)) = 'T1')
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at GUI.Login_Check.CoLogin(Login_Check.java:27)
    at GUI.Login.btnSubmitActionPerformed(Login.java:208)
    at GUI.Login.access$200(Login.java:17)
    at GUI.Login$3.actionPerformed(Login.java:110)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException: Comparisons between 'INTEGER' and 'CHAR (UCS_BASIC)' are not supported. Types must be comparable. String types must also have matching collation. If collation does not match, a possible solution is to cast operands to force them to the default collation (e.g. SELECT tablename FROM sys.systables WHERE CAST(tablename AS VARCHAR(128)) = 'T1')
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.completeSqlca(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parsePrepareError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parsePRPSQLSTTreply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.readPrepareDescribeOutput(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.StatementReply.readPrepareDescribeOutput(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatement.readPrepareDescribeOutput_(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.readPrepareDescribeOutput(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.flowExecute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.executeQueryX(Unknown Source)
    ... 41 more`

Code:

```
public static void CoLogin(String username, String password){
    try{
        String dbuser = "";
        String dbpass = "";
        String url = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Java-App";
        String user = username;
        String pass = password;
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "admin", "admin");

        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        String SQL = "SELECT * FROM MEMBERS WHERE ID='" + user + "' && PASSWORD='" + pass + "'";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);

        while(rs.next()){
            dbuser= rs.getString("ID");
            dbpass = rs.getString("PASSWORD");
        }
        if(user.equals(dbuser) && pass.equals(dbpass)){
                 Main x = new Main();
                 x.setVisible(true);
        } 
        else{
            Login x = new Login();
            x.setVisible(true);
        }

        //Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user,     pass);

    }
    catch(SQLException error){
        System.out.println(error.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: Your error description "However, this is not the case" is too vague. A good way to dig deeper into the root cause of your problem is debugging. Check if `rs.next()` returns `true` at least once. Check the values returned by `rs.getString("ID")` and `rs.getString("PASSWORD")`. Check if there is no error in the System Error log. This will narrow down your root problem and, even if you cannot understand its cause, come back again with the results and we can help.

Comment: Does `&&` even work? I would have expected it to be `AND`. You should also be using parameterised queries instead of dumping the values directly into the query string to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: @RobertoLinares I added a sout to print rs.getString value and it just returns the same connection authentication failure occurred. So it basically goes straight to the catch statement.

Comment: Can you add to the question the stack trace printed by the exception?

Comment: @RobertoLinares done

Answer (score 1):

According to your log, the root cause of your error is at the momment you establish the connection to your database, in th line:

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "admin", "admin");
```

The error messsage `Connection authentication failure occurred.  Reason: Userid or password invalid.` is telling you that the "admin" user or passowrd you are using to connect to your derby database is incorrect.

What you can do is, before using that authentication data to connect to your database, check them in a database client like the **Data Source Explorer** in Eclpise or the **Data Base Explorer** in Netbeans. Once you are sure that your database's authentication data is correct, use it in your code.

Comment: Additionally, for background information on how Derby implements connection authentication, see the authentication chapters in the manual: https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.12/security/

Comment: Thanks, it was uppercase admin. However I have come across another error.

Comment: Well, the error seems to be related to the data types in your `MEMBERS`  table. In your query you assume that both `ID` and `PASSWORD` fields are of type `VARCHAR` but the error suggests that one of them is really of type `INTEGER` so the comparison in the query is not valid. Check the data types again and I would also suggest you to try the query in a database client first.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem could have many causes.

However, if a user types username="", password="" he's going to be authenticated on any case. Also mind about [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).